# FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:Program Files\\Java' in library h2o python

Tags: python, java

I want to ask, why if i am trying to run library h2o in my jupyter notebook show error message "FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:Program Files\Java'"..
I try in CMD and anaconda prompt " java -version" sucess/java starting but in  jupyter notebook java is not starting

thanks before

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to place a `\` after the root folder.

It should be

```
C:\Program Files\Java
```

Comment: in my environment after the root folder always "\"..
I checked back and in my environment after the root folder same with your example..
thank you for your answer